# can a covariate also be a random effect in linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I have a problem where I have 5 different patients who have given their blood. And each of these samples is treated with 6 different compounds. These samples are assayed for a panel of 50 proteins and we finally get the protein abundances for each of these samples.

So I am interested in looking at how the protein abundances change with the treatment. My sample size ( no. of donors ) is small, and the variance among them is pretty large, I want to use the donor ID as the random effect. But the same donors are used in obtaining repeated measures at a further time point as well.

So my question is - can I use the donor ID as the covariate as well as the random effect in my model?

abundance ~ treatment + donor + (1|donor)

Does the above model make sense?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think that makes sense.  You use random effects for donor ID to account for heterogeneity across individuals without devoting a whole degree of freedom to each individual which would have resulted in instability.  You would get a singular model if you put ID in two places.  And note that to use random effects you need lots of IDs with more than one observation.  But for your situation the serial nature of the data may better be handled with a serial correlation approach, keeping ID random effects to handle the non-longitudinal part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So I used 2 different models to do this based on your explanation
1. ANOVA , where covariate is donor ID and 2. LMM where the random effect is donor ID.
Also, I was wondering if the donor ID can be used in interaction with the treatment like so: 
abundance ~ treatment*donor + (1|donor)

Comment: If the number of donors is large in comparison with the total effective sample size, the treatment*donor interaction terms will be severely shrunken, but that may be the best you can do.  You can use the estimated variance of the interaction random effects to quantify evidence for such donor heterogeneity.

Answer (score 2):

> abundance ~ treatment + donor + (1|donor)
>
> Does the above model make sense?

No, it doesn't. For one thing, it is unlikely that such a model is identified. For another, it may result in convergence problems.

Either it should be random, or fixed. It can't really be both.